# How to use a USNO Moonrise & Sunrise JSON data array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, time, astronomy

This is my first question here. I hack myself forward slowly slowly. I want to present this JSON data URL as HTML. Showing both sunrise and moonrise, sets etc. Below is pasted the JSON URL, the JSON and my messy non-working script that have not gotten to the moon data yet. That Problary was closer to it hours ago. The problem is the JSON arrayed data I think. After it all I paste the API page. Really hope that someone will be able to assist. : Thank you.

Marcus

PS. Please be clear, noobie alert! one-liners & cryptic examples hardly do it for me.

## URL

```
http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=today&coords=9S,147E&tz=10
```

## JSON

```
{
"error":false,
"apiversion":"2.0.0",
"year":2017,
"month":3,
"day":4,
"dayofweek":"Saturday",
"datechanged":false,
"lon":147.000000,
"lat":9.000000,
"tz":10,

"sundata":[
            {"phen":"BC", "time":"06:04"},
            {"phen":"R", "time":"06:25"},
            {"phen":"U", "time":"12:24"},
            {"phen":"S", "time":"18:23"},
            {"phen":"EC", "time":"18:44"}],

"moondata":[
            {"phen":"R", "time":"10:50"},
            {"phen":"U", "time":"17:12"},
            {"phen":"S", "time":"23:36"}],

"closestphase":{"phase":"First Quarter","date":"March 5, 2017","time":"21:32"},
"fracillum":"34%",
"curphase":"Waxing Crescent"
}
```

## UPDATED! STATE OF CODE

```
$.getJSON("http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=today&coords=9S,147E&tz=10", function(data) {

    data.sundata.forEach(function (sd) {
    $('#'+sd.phen).text(sd.time)
  })
var rise = data.moondata[0].time;
var tran = data.moondata[1].time;
var sets = data.moondata[2].time;

    // Set the table td text
    $('#R').text(rise);
    $('#U').text(tran);
    $('#S').text(sets);
}

})
```

CODE AS EARLIER

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=today&coords=9S,147E&tz=10", function(data) {
    console.log(data);


        // Set the variables from the results array
        var dusk = ["sundata"][0]["BC.time"];
        console.log(data);

        var rise = ["sundata"][0]["R.time"];
        console.log(data);

        var noon = ["sundata"][0]["U.time"]
        console.log(data);

        var sets = ["sundata"][0]["S.time"];
        console.log(data);

        var dawn = ["sundata"][0]["EC.time"];
        console.log(data);

        // Set the table td text
        $('BC').text(dusk);
        $('R').text(rise);
        $('U').text(noon);
        $('S').text(sets);
        $('EC').text(dawn);
    });           
    </script>          
    </head>       
    <body>           
    <h1>MOONSUN</h1>   
        <hr/>
        <table border="1">        
                <td>DAWN:</td>
                <td id="BC"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>RISE:</td>
                <td id="R"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>NOON:</td>
                <td id="U"></td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>SET:</td>
                <td id="S"></td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>DUSK:</td>
                <td id="EC"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

## API LINK

http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/api.php

## NEW JSFIDDLE

[link]http://jsfiddle.net/kmg747/4egLxu2e/

Comment: I wished you would have seen that this problem had been solved before closing it, 'to broad' is categorized wrong according to me. The question asked to solve a particular problem. And it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you need to access the data object to get any information `var dusk = data["sundata"][0]["BC.time"]`. Pay attention to the data object there.

The way you are accessing/handling data from array and nested objects are wrong too. The endpoint is returning an object with properties as String, Boolan or Array (`[]`) of Objects (`{}`).

To access an Array you do by index, as in `arr[0]`, for an Object you do `obj.propertyIWant` or `obj['propertyIWant']`

And to access an element by id with jQuery you need the `#` before the element id, like `$('#BC')`.

For what you want to do you should do something like:

```
var dusk = data.sundata[0].time;
var rise = data.sundata[1].time;
var noon = data.sundata[2].time;
var sets = data.sundata[3].time;
var dawn = data.sundata[4].time;
```

Or, in a more direct way, without setting those variables, using the information you got from the endpoint:

```
data.sundata.forEach(function (sd) {
  $('#'+sd.phen).text(sd.time)
})
```

Fetching the url from your JSFiddle link doesn't work because you are using an HTTPS connection and are trying to fetch from an HTTP link. To work, you need to use the Fiddle from HTTP. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default#Mixed_active_content).

After checking the [API](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/api.php#rstt) for it, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ffkkurzm/) is an updated version of what you are trying to do. You may need to treat some values that may or may not be returned.

Comment: Thank you very much man. Think I will be able to add the Moon data now.

Comment: Hi @kmg! Welcome to StackOverflow. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Howdy @giorni Thanks again. However I still have problems since both the sun and the moon data share some id's that overtook the sundata and replaced it by the moondata it is the 'R', 'U' and 'S'   
Got that to work separately however by using this:
var rise = data.moondata[1].time;
var noon = data.moondata[2].time;
var sets = data.moondata[3].time;

Comment: Hey again @giorni.. and when I added the last JSON bits it broke. So tried to go backwards but then feel asleep.  I see if I can find it now.. and update with a new JSfiddle and the last bit of the JSON with the moonphase is also troublesome, I managed to break the code somehow.

Comment: Sorry about this multiple messages@giorni, unable to use carriage return for some reason. HOpefully accesible JSfiddle above.  The overtaking took place was when i duplicated the code below and made into moondata. data.sundata.forEach(function (sd) {
  $('#'+sd.phen).text(sd.time)
})

Comment: No problem @kmg. Updated it with a new example. Also, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for some guidelines using StackOverflow. Hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: Super nice! @giorni Runs as clockwork. Hope you are having a nice and all. Thank you.